# Trying to talk with Arduino bluetooth using CBCentralManager

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I am currently working on a project where a LTE bluetooth module in arduino sends out messages to the Iphone. I started the iphone app reading through the apple doc for CBCentral manager and i cam up with this code

```
-(instancetype)init{

self = [super init];
if(self){

    self.bluetoothManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:nil];

}

return self;
```

}

```
-(instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id<BLEDelegate>)delegate{

self = [self init];
self.delegate = delegate;

return self;
```

}

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
  NSLog(@"called");

}
```

when i instantiate the CBCentralManager and set delegate and self and start the app, The centralManagerDidUpdateState is not getting called.

Comment: What device are you running on?